# How to transfer chat conversation history of Pidgin from one computer to another?

Tags: pidgin

I am moving to a new computer. Is it possible to have all the chat history transferred from the old PC to the new one?

Comment: I think this link would help you !!

[Transfer Pidgin settings][1]



  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/36056/how-to-transfer-pidgin-settings-from-one-computer-to-another

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and account configurations. Just copy the purple hidden directory in your home.

~/.purple

You can learn about .purple location and other frequent asqued questions in pidgin FAQ.

https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Pidgin#Whereismy.purpledirectory